# Why committing a docker image causes a <none>:<none> image to be created?

Tags: docker, containers

It's visible when I execute the command:

```
docker images -a
```

Or even with **docker images**, sometimes.

I commit the changes on the container to the image with:

```
docker run -it --name alezuechcontainer alezuech/denoising:version1

# doing some stuff inside the container

exit

docker commit alezuechcontainer alezuech/denoising:version1

docker rm alezuechcontainer
```

The list of images is like this:

```
docker image ls --all
REPOSITORY               TAG                           IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
alezuech/denoising       version1                      67aee2******   12 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        1e52de******   12 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        7dd6c0******   13 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        9df296******   14 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        337f8d******   14 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        2cbfaf******  17 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        77c13f******   18 hours ago    14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        e390c7******   3 weeks ago     14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        98eb41******   3 weeks ago     14.5GB
<none>                   <none>                        cd1e36******   3 weeks ago     14.4GB
<none>                   <none>                        02ca34******   3 weeks ago     14.4GB
<none>                   <none>                        2a168a******   3 weeks ago     14.4GB
<none>                   <none>                        7c92d9******   6 weeks ago     14.4GB
<none>                   <none>                        b799c6******   2 months ago    14.4GB
```

The original image was obtained with:

```
docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:22.05-tf1-py3
```

And how do I prevent them from appearing?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @BMitch answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Those are dangling images. It's the old image that got overwritten, since you committed with the same name and tag as the image you ran. You can't have two different images with the same name and tag.

Note, you shouldn't use commit. Only in emergency cases. It's best practice to use Dockerfiles to make your image repeatable. If you ever lose the image or container, you can always get it back from the Dockerfile.

Comment: I thought that commits worked like git and that I could substitute the old image with the new one. Thank you

Comment: I still have the problem of the <none>:<none> images. After I apply `docker rmi` to one image, it just untags it, and then I can't delete it because it has child dependencies.